# Are there any writings which speak to the spiritual aspects of different materials (Metals/Wood/etc.)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, jewish-books, soul, thought, gold

[**I found an article on Chabad which got into some spiritual ideas around metals.**](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/622664/jewish/Snake-Metal.htm) It specifically touches on Gold, Silver, and Copper and relates each to various concepts of holiness and spiritual qualities and the soul and so on.

It was an interesting read and I haven't heard of metals spoken about and related to spiritual philosophy in such a way. I was curious if there are any books or writings or philosophies which codify and organize these or similar ideas about elements?

- Metals
- Woods
- Elements
- Things of this nature

Comment: I saw a sefer once that went through the properties of the materials donated to Mishkan, but I don't remember the name.

Comment: I saw something that said that the Egyptians infused their gold and silver with the forces of klipa and tumah - in order to defile the Bnei Yisrael. Interestingly when the Yidden took these spoils post krias yam suf, it was this koach that helped make the Golden Calf come about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably enjoy looking through [Midrash Talpiot on the section dealing with all the various stones](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20804&st=&pgnum=22&hilite=), both precious and otherwise. It has extensive discussion of precisely what you are requesting with a listing of where each subject is found in Torah literature.

Concerning [wood (עץ)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=220) generally, Sefer Kehillat Yaacov should be looked at. Some specific metals are also listed in this excellent reference and don't forget to look at the *Omissions* (השמטות) pages too when checking there.

A similar and earlier reference work to check into is [Sefer Ma'orot Natan](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33030&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=).

Answer (score 0):

Rav S. R. Hirsch writes on this, see his essay on the Mishkan in "Jewish Symbolism" (Collected Writings vol. III).

Comment: it would be great if you could share some of what he says?